# Some facts to prove in Permutation group theory

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Definiton : Let $g \in \text{Sym}(\Omega)$, then graph of $g$ is $$\Delta_g = \{(\omega,\omega^g) \mid \omega \in \Omega \} \subseteq \Omega \times \Omega $$

**Facts :** Let $g,h,h_1,h_2 \in \text{Sym}(\Omega)$

1. $\Delta _{h_{1}} = \Delta _{h_{2}}$ if and only if $h_1 = h_2$
2. $(\Delta_h)^g = \Delta_{h^{g}}$
3. $gh = hg$ if and only if $(\Delta_h)^g = \Delta_{h}$

Proof of first is easy from the definition.
How to prove the second and third facts?

Proof of 2nd : $(\Delta_h)^g = \{\omega^g,\omega^{hg}\ \mid  \omega \in \Omega\} = \{(\pi,\pi^{g^{-1}hg} \mid \pi \in \Omega\} = \Delta_{g^{-1}hg} = \Delta_{h^g}$. I did not get the last step i.e. $\Delta_{g^{-1}hg} = \Delta_{h^g}$

Comment: by definition, $h^g=g^{-1}hg$

Comment: @ idok I am not able follow could you explain it how?

Comment: how do you define $h^g$?

Comment: There is nothing to understand. As idok says, $h^g$ is equal to $g^{-1}hg$ by definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two meaning here to $x^g$, one for when $x$ is an element of $\Omega$ and one for when $x$ is an element of $G$.

When $x\in \Omega$, one writes $x^g=g(x)$ ($g$ is a bijection of $\Omega$ onto itself).

When $x\in G$, the operation $x^g$ is the group conjugation, i.e, $x^g=g^-1\cdot x\cdot g$.

So in the proof the 2nd statement, $(\Delta_H)^g=\{g((\omega,\omega^h )): \omega\in \Omega\}$ (when we view $\Delta_H$ as a subset of $\Omega\times\Omega$). But $g((\omega,\omega^h ))=(\omega^g,\omega^{hg})$ and therefore  $$(\Delta_H)^g=\{g((\omega,\omega^h )): \omega\in \Omega\}=\{(\omega^g,\omega^{hg}):\omega\in \Omega\}$$

Cutting to the last equation, $\Delta_{g^{-1}hg}=\Delta_{h^g}$, here we view the operation $h^g$ as conjugation in the group, since $h\in G$.

After you get all of that, you just need to verify that you understand the second equation, and the proof is complete.